# How can I do what this app does? How is this technique called?

Tags: image, image-processing, video, video-processing

recently I saw an app in the playstore:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.donalddraws.app

(Not trying to make this political, I couldnt find another example)

Basically, you give an image of a given size to the app and the app will put the image inside the video, resizing and transforming the image automatically so it looks like it is part of the video.

So the programmer have to let the app know where the image should be placed and how it should be transformed.

Example video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zvf3yeZYUiI

I tried searching information, but couldnt find much, maybe I am not using the right terms.

It probably looks like a broad question, but I'm just looking for the name of the technique or a small introduction (preferably Python, but other languages would be fine too).

Thank you!

Comment: your question is indeed to broad.

Try keywords like homography, perspective, transformation

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html

    https://ramsrigoutham.com/2014/06/14/perspective-projection-with-homography-opencv/          https://ags.cs.uni-kl.de/fileadmin/inf_ags/3dcv-ws11-12/3DCV_WS11-12_lec04.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the links, I will look it up